# jquery continuous animation on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, mouseover

I am trying to have an animation run only when the mouse is over an object. I can get one iteration of the animation and then have it set back to normal on mouse out. But I'd like the animation to loop on mouseover. How would I do it, using setInterval? I'm a little stuck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be done like this:

```
$.fn.loopingAnimation = function(props, dur, eas)
{
    if (this.data('loop') == true)
    {
       this.animate( props, dur, eas, function() {
           if( $(this).data('loop') == true ) $(this).loopingAnimation(props, dur, eas);
       });
    }

    return this; // Don't break the chain
}
```

Now, you can do this:

```
$("div.animate").hover(function(){
     $(this).data('loop', true).stop().loopingAnimation({ left: "+10px"}, 300);
}, function(){
     $(this).data('loop', false);
     // Now our animation will stop after fully completing its last cycle
});
```

If you wanted the animation *immediately* stop, you could change the `hoverOut` line to read:

```
$(this).data('loop', false).stop();
```

Comment: I had to switch my answer due to problems wtih recursion. I can't seem to get you answer to work with the loopingAnimation method - if I change it to "animate", it does one iteration.

Comment: Doug, the *animate* call was missing closing parenthesis so I added it but it wasn't enough to save since you need at least 6 chars modifications so I indented your code for that purpose. FYI.

Answer (score 4):

`setInterval` returns an id that can be passed to `clearInterval` to disable the timer.

You can write the following:

```
var timerId;

$(something).hover(
    function() {
        timerId = setInterval(function() { ... }, 100);
    },
    function() { clearInterval(timerId); }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed this to work for more then one object on the page so I modified a little Cletus's code :

```
var over = false;
$(function() {
  $("#hovered-item").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("position", "relative");
    over = true;
    swinger = this;
    grow_anim();
  }, function() {
    over = false;
  });
});

function grow_anim() {
  if (over) {
    $(swinger).animate({left: "5px"}, 200, 'linear', shrink_anim);
  }
}

function shrink_anim() {
  $(swinger).animate({left: "0"}, 200, 'linear', grow_anim);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
<div id="anim">This is a test</div>
```

with:

```
#anim { padding: 15px; background: yellow; }
```

and:

```
var over = false;
$(function() {
  $("#anim").hover(function() {
    over = true;
    grow_anim();
  }, function() {
    over = false;
  });
});

function grow_anim() {
  if (over) {
    $("#anim").animate({paddingLeft: "100px"}, 1000, shrink_anim);
  }
}

function shrink_anim() {
  $("#anim").animate({paddingLeft: "15px"}, 1000, grow_anim);
}
```

You can achieve this using timers too.

Comment: Cool solution. I'm still a novice at JS. How would I make this generic so if I had several anims, I would assume I would pass in the id in the function and then call it each time for each type? can the function() part there take parameters, and hwo would I call it for each kind, is that really the best solution?