# too much recursion in javascript with jquery mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a JS novice. Using some code I found here to help me with mouseover scale/rotate images but now when I try to apply it to more than one object I'm getting errors saying "too much recursion". Before the function didn't take any arguments, it just was on s_1 and it worked fine. I am tempted to just write different code for each object but that isn't very good programming practice.

```
            var over = false;
            $(function(){
                $("#s_1").hover(function(){
                    over = true;
                    swing_left_anim("#s_1");
                }, function(){
                    over = false;
                });
   $("#np_1").hover(function(){
                    over = true;
                    swing_left_anim("np_1");
                }, function(){
                    over = false;
                });
            });

            function swing_left_anim(obj){
                $(obj).animate({
                    rotate: '0deg'
                }, {
                    duration: 500
                });
                if (over) {
                    $(obj).animate({
                        rotate: '25deg'
                    }, 500, swing_right_anim(obj));

                }
            }

            function swing_right_anim(obj){
                $(obj).animate({
                    rotate: '-25deg'
                }, 500, swing_left_anim(obj));
            }
```

Comment: it looks like swing_left_anim and swing_right_anim keep on calling each other. Was it like that before you edited it?

Comment: I was using the code in this example that I accepted, and it was working.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039750/jquery-continuous-animation-on-mouseover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is jQuery bug. A callback must be a separate object every time you call animate(), beacause jQuery is copying reference of function (or object, it depends on chosen variant of animate()). More details here: http://blog.stephenrushing.com/index.php/jquery/jqueryanimate-too-much-recursion-from-complete-callback/

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing the `#` on this string input

```
swing_left_anim("np_1");
```

Not sure if this is the only problem with the code though, can you put an example up on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) and post the url as an edit in your question?

Also, take a look at the [easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) for different kinds of animation effects.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I'm still getting the error, though.

Does the easing plugin support scaling and swing animation? It's for images to make them swing back and forth and scale up slightly.