# JQuery thumbnail src rotator on hover (multiple images)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hover, rotation

**Situation:** We've got this DIV with thumbnails who need their src being changed on hover:

```
<div id="moreVideos">
<span class="mb">
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:loadAndPlayVideo('qrO4YZeyl0I');return false;" class="ml">
        <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/qrO4YZeyl0I/default.jpg" id="thumb_qrO4YZeyl0I" class="mvThumb" title="Lady Gaga - Bad Romance">
    </a
</span>
<span class="mb">
    <a class="ml" onclick="javascript:loadAndPlayVideo('niqrrmev4mA');return false;" href="#">
        <img title="Lady Gaga - Alejandro" class="mvThumb" id="thumb_niqrrmev4mA" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/niqrrmev4mA/default.jpg">
    </a>
</span>
<span class="mb">
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:loadAndPlayVideo('qrO4YZeyl0I');return false;" class="ml">
        <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/qrO4YZeyl0I/default.jpg" id="thumb_qrO4YZeyl0I" class="mvThumb" title="Lady Gaga - Bad Romance">
    </a
</span>
<span class="mb">
    <a class="ml" onclick="javascript:loadAndPlayVideo('niqrrmev4mA');return false;" href="#">
        <img title="Lady Gaga - Alejandro" class="mvThumb" id="thumb_niqrrmev4mA" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/niqrrmev4mA/default.jpg">
    </a>
</span>
```

**Problem:** On thumbnail hover we need to change the thumbnail src every 2 seconds from default.jpg -> 1.jpg -> 2.jpg -> 3.jpg -> default.jpg (loop through them while the mouse is hovering the thumb, after mouse out it need to stop and stay on the current image)

**What I've tried:** Plenty of sample codes from other websites and the JQuery cycle plugin. Trying to use this solution failed: [jquery continuous animation on mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039750/jquery-continuous-animation-on-mouseover/2039769#2039769)

**Will be used on:** http://ListAndPlay.com

I'm very curious in how you would solve a problem like this :)!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ayNPS/))... I also extracted out the inline call to loadAndPlayVideo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('a.ml').click(function(){
  loadAndPlayVideo( $(this).find('img').attr('id').replace(/thumb_/,'') );
  return false;
 });

 var timer,
  count = 0,
  cycle = function(el){
    var s = el.attr('src'),
     root = s.substring( 0, s.lastIndexOf('/') + 1 );
    count = (count+1)%4;
    el.attr('src', root + ((count===0) ? 'default' : count) + '.jpg');
 };

 $('.mb img').hover(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   cycle($this);
   timer = setInterval(function(){ cycle($this); }, 1000);
 }, function(){
   clearInterval(timer);
 });

});
```

HTML

```
<!-- changed the "moreVideos" id to class, assuming you'll have more than one block -->
<div class="moreVideos"> 
<span class="mb">
    <a class="ml" href="#">
        <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/qrO4YZeyl0I/default.jpg" id="thumb_qrO4YZeyl0I" class="mvThumb" title="Lady Gaga - Bad Romance">
    </a
</span>
<span class="mb">
    <a class="ml" href="#">
        <img title="Lady Gaga - Alejandro" class="mvThumb" id="thumb_niqrrmev4mA" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/niqrrmev4mA/default.jpg">
    </a>
</span>
<span class="mb">
    <a class="ml" href="#">
        <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/qrO4YZeyl0I/default.jpg" id="thumb_qrO4YZeyl0I" class="mvThumb" title="Lady Gaga - Bad Romance">
    </a
</span>
<span class="mb">
    <a class="ml" href="#">
        <img title="Lady Gaga - Alejandro" class="mvThumb" id="thumb_niqrrmev4mA" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/niqrrmev4mA/default.jpg">
    </a>
</span>
```

---

**Update**: To have a variable number of thumbs for each image, I [updated the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ayNPS/358/) too allow you to add a `data-thumbs` attribute containing either the file name (if all thumbs use the same root url), or full urls for each thumb.

```
<img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/qrO4YZeyl0I/default.jpg" data-thumbs="default.jpg, 1.jpg, http://i.ytimg.com/vi/qrO4YZeyl0I/2.jpg, 3.jpg" id="thumb_qrO4YZeyl0I" class="mvThumb" title="Lady Gaga - Bad Romance">
```

For example, the above image will only work if the url for thumb "2.jpg" has the same root (`http://i.ytimg.com/vi/qrO4YZeyl0I/`) as used in the "src" attribute because the code is modifying the url of the currently shown url. For images in different locations, use the full url for each thumb inside the `data-thumbs` attribute.

```
$(function() {

  $('a.ml').click(function() {
    loadAndPlayVideo($(this).find('img').attr('id').replace(/thumb_/, ''));
    return false;
  });

  var timer;

  function cycle(el) {
    var s = el.attr('src'),
      root = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
      files = el.attr('data-thumbs').split(/\s*,\s*/),
      count = parseInt(el.attr('data-count'), 10) || 0;
    count = (count + 1) % files.length;
    el.attr({
      'src': files[count].indexOf('http') > -1 ? files[count] : root + files[count],
      'data-count': count
    });
  }

  $('.mb img').hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    cycle($this);
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      cycle($this);
    }, 1000);
  }, function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  });

});
```

Comment: Fudgey you're amazing! The code is perfect and I finally understand how to approach problems like these in the future, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad that you got what you needed. Did you need me to add some comments in the script, in case there is something that isn't clear?

Comment: Wow dat so boss!

Answer (score 1):

I hate to start a whole new question and have to copy Mottie's code in this question to ask it. The answer posted works great, and my only question is how to modify it to allow a variable number of thumbnail images.

The example shown loops from default.jpg -> 1.jpg -> 2.jpg -> 3.jpg -> default.jpg which is great if you have only four images in each directory of thumbnails. But what if there are a different number of thumbs for each of the image src links? For example, what if the first image has 6 thumbs, the second image has 8 thumbs, and the third image has 11 thumbs. What's the secret to making the code not care how many thumbs are in the directory of images so it will loop through all of them regardless of the number of thumbs?

Comment: Wow, sorry 3 years later!... I've updated my answer to show the modified code. Next time go ahead and start a new question, or add a comment as this isn't a real answer and will likely get deleted.