# jQuery Mouse Hover Animate Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, I have this container, then inside it, it has contents. To navigate it, the user has to hover the button **(up or down)** for the container to move.

If I click the arrow up button, the container should not go top since the position of the container is 0. It should remain the same like this one.

Here's the screen shot for you guys to understand.

[image]
**and...** 
[image]

Here's the reference where I got the code

[jquery continuous animation on mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039750/jquery-continuous-animation-on-mouseover)

Any help would be appreciated, This is the js fiddlink --> [JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Vigiliance/9xLm6/)

**Code: (required by SO)**

```
$.fn.loopingAnimation = function(props, dur, eas)
  {
      if (this.data('loop') == true)
      {
         this.animate( props, dur, eas, function() {
            if( $(this).data('loop') == true ) $(this).loopingAnimation(props, dur, eas);
         });
      }
      return this;
}

var height = $("#recipeIndex1").height();

$(".btnUp").hover(function() {

    $(".recipeIndex").data('loop', true).stop().loopingAnimation({ top: "+"+ height +"px"}, 2000);
  }, function() {
    $(".recipeIndex").stop();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
newH =  $('.recipeIndexImage img:first').offset().top < 0 ? 0 : height;
```

**Full code**

```
$(".btnUp").hover(function () {
    newH = $('.recipeIndexImage img:first').offset().top < 0 ? 0 : height;
    $(".recipeIndex").data('loop', true).stop().loopingAnimation({
        top: "+" + newH + "px"
    }, 2000);
}, function () {
    $(".recipeIndex").stop();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9xLm6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
step:function(now,fx)
{

if(now<0)
//stop animate here

}
```

in animate() http://api.jquery.com/animate/